# Drawing a rectangle in UIGraphics context does not work

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to overlay an image with some extra information: some text and rectangles. Right now I am stuck at drawing the rectangles. They just won't show up. What am I doing wrong? The image itself is being drawn, so the graphics context must be ok.

```
- (void)drawTag:(NSString *)tag withRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Set the color in the current graphics context for future draw operations
    [[UIColor yellowColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];

    // Create our drawing path
    UIBezierPath* drawingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];

    // actually draw it
    [drawingPath stroke];
}

- (IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender
{
    // draw the image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.userImage.size);
    // This one shows up:
    [self.userImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    // This one does not:
    [self drawTag:@"Test" withRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    // Show the whole thing:
    self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.imageViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imageViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `lineWidth` property of `UIBezierPath` to a value >= 1

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that does not help either. I also just read that I should use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext and UIGraphicsPushContext, because I am not drawing on a UIView, but that also did not help.

Comment: Well you're drawing inside a graphics context you create for drawing inside a bitmap.. does drawing with CoreGraphics directly work? (using CGPath)

Comment: Ok, I was pretty dumb: My UIImageView was set to Aspect Fill. So the coordinates lay outside the view... I now set it to Aspect Fit, which is more like what I wanted, and now I see my rectangles. :)